# WooCommerce duplicate slugs for categories

Tags: woocommerce, slug

I am trying to setup a mobile store with woocommerce and I have some problems when I am creating categories.

For an example;
Category 1 :
Product Apple
Category 2 :
Product apple

and I want to display the URL like below

```
www.site.com/category-1/product-apple
www.site.com/category-2/product-apple
www.site.com/category-3/product-apple
```

But now when I am creating the second category called "product-apple" it says slug already exist.

How can I solve this problem ?

```
wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/
```